# MeteorJS: use mongo shell without building meteor app

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Meteor apps usually take a while to build. Also, you cannot use `meteor mongo` until the app is built and running. Is there a way to use the mongo shell and read the MondoDB data without building the app?

Edit: I am not trying to connect an external mongodb instance to meteor. The meteor project is already associated with a db, I just want to run the mongo shell from command line without having to build the project.

Comment: How is this a duplicate @Neil ? I am not trying to "connect an external mongodb instance".

Comment: Since I can't post an answer, I'll answer here. In development, Meteor starts a local mongoDB instance when Meteor starts. So you can't access the database unless Meteor is running because Meteor runs mongoDB. 

The only way around this is to use an external mongoDB instance which continues to run when meteor is not running

Comment: Make sure you have Mongodb installed (as you need mongod). Also, make sure your MeteorJS application is stopped, to prevent having 2 Mongodb servers using the same set of data (or change its `MONGO_URL`). Run `mongod --dbpath .meteor/local/db`. This will launch a Mongodb server. You can connect to it via mongo shell without having your Meteor app running.